# Check RadioButton by Variable (It's name)

Tags: c#, radio-button

I want to check a RadioButton by its name. It's name is stored in a variable. How can I do this? Here's my code so far:

```
string str = "";
str = so._settingValue; // RadioButton name
RadioButton(str).Checked = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using this code within a `WinForm` (`System.Windows.Forms`)... so...

```
RadioButton button = this.Controls[name];
// where name is a string
```

Example:

```
String name = "MyRadioButton";
RadioButton button = (RadioButton)this.Controls[name];
Boolean isChecked = button.Checked;
```

If the control is **nested** into another control (a Panel or something like this), the above solution doesn't work... you have to use this one:

```
String name = "MyRadioButton";
RadioButton button = this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault() as RadioButton;
Boolean isChecked = button.Checked;
```

Comment: Ok I fixed my answer, sorry!

Comment: this line: button.Checked = true; is giving me null reference exception error. This also doesn't work: this.button.Checked = true;

Comment: Ok wait wait wait... first, you have to be sure that your control name is matching the string you are looking for. Then, the control must not be nested (inserted into another control). I'm gonna update the answer for nested controls...

Comment: yes, I have a groupbox. no I don't want to get check state. I want to set it.

Comment: That's why. Use the second method.

Comment: I replaced last line with button.Checked = true; and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!